# How to change limit concurent threads in WCF (20 threads by core)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, wcf, parallel-processing

I create very simple WCF server ( console application):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IalzFirst
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Hi();
}

public class alzFirst : IalzFirst
{
    public string Hi()
    {
        var tid = (int)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId(); ;
        Thread.Sleep(9000);
        return String.Format("Hi from thread id = {0}",tid);
    }
}
class Program
{    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8123/hi");
        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(alzFirst), baseAddress))
        {
            // Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
            // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
            // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
            // by the service.
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and client for him:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var srv = new alzService.IalzFirstClient();
        var ret =srv.Hi();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var x = i;
            Task<int> t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = srv.Hi();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-> {1}", x, result);
                    return x;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!! --- Error--- !!! On step {0} : {1}",x, e.Message);
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        }
        Console.Write("!!!! 0 result = {0}",ret);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

as you can see - client create 10 000 (-1) tasks, so I can see how many threads WCF server will create.

But always, in any configurations count of threads on WCF server maximum 80-82 threads ( in Process explorer) - that mean I have treshold 20*count of cpu core ( in my case = 4).

Can I increase count of threads more than 80 (in my case) ?

Comment: see "[Using ServiceThrottlingBehavior to Control WCF Service Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114(v=vs.100).aspx)"

Comment: Thank you very much ! After adding section <serviceThrottling> with maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentSessions, and maxConcurrentInstances problem resolved. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer to the question and mark it accepted or delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add section `<serviceThrottling>` like this:

```
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior  name="Throttled">
        <serviceThrottling
          maxConcurrentCalls="1000"
          maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
          maxConcurrentInstances="1000"
      />
        <serviceMetadata
          httpGetEnabled="false"
          httpGetUrl=""
      />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

and add reference in `<service>` section like this:

```
 <services>
    <service name ="SelfHostedWCF.alzFirst" behaviorConfiguration="Throttled">
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:8123/hi" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IalzFirst" contract="SelfHostedWCF.IalzFirst"
      />
    </service>
  </services>
```